# The program can't start because libmwsl_solver_rtw.dll is missing?

Tags: windows, matlab, simulink

I generated an executable from a simulink coder using the 'rsim' target build,but the executable is missing this dll. When using 'grt' target build, this dll error isn't called, the executable runs as expected.

Any ideas what is this dll and where it maybe found ?

Comment: What solver are you using? Are you running it on the same machine as you created the exe on, or a different machine? If a different machine, does it have Simulink installed on it?

Comment: The solver is fixed step, and I am running it on the same machine windows . But it is meant to run as a  windows standalone executable that reads a mat file when starting (mat file has values for constants inside the model executable). This standalone executable must not depend on matlab or simulink

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to find the library location  (matlab\R2016a\bin\win64) and added the path to Environment variables